# Unable to workout href Class - Tag

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I have never posted HTML before, so not sure if I have done it correctly. I am trying to get the href from the html below.

This is the Url [Link](https://www.walmart.com/ip/VIZIO-24-Class-HD-LED-Smart-TV-D-Series-D24h-G9/733526938)

I have tried several variations of my code, from `GetClass` `GetClass With GetTag "Span"` and  `GetClass With GetTag "Span" + "a"` however I can not workout what the class is. It looks straight forward, However I am stuck on this one.

```html
<section class="prod-SellerSection bot-border-bottom">
    <div class="Grid-col">
        <div data-tl-id="ProductSellerInfo-ProductSellerInfo" class="SellerInfo">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="elc-icon xs-margin-right valign-middle elc- icon-spark elc-icon-18"></span>
            <span data-tl-id="ProductSellerInfo-SoldShippedBy" class="SellerInfo-shipping-msg"> <span class="no-wrap">Sold &amp; shipped by</span></span>
            <a class="seller-name" href="https://help.walmart.com/article/shipping-and-delivery-with-walmart-com/0fa824faeca24e599e0e5292a7185336" data-tl-id="ProductSellerInfo-SellerName" tabindex="0">Walmart</a>
            <div class="display-inline-block">
                <button class="button SellerInfo-return-policy button--link" data-automation-id="button" data-tl-id="ProductSellerInfoReturnPolicyModal-ReturnPolicy" type="button"><span class="button-wrapper">Return policy</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is my latest variation with **Class + Span + a**

N.B. I have removed the class as I can not work it out.

```
For Each link In varLinks
    DoEvents
    Set doc = NewHTMLDocument(CStr(link))
    ''''Get Link 1
    If doc.getElementsByClassName("")(0).getElementsByTagName("Span")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0) Is Nothing Then
        wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = "-"
    Else
        wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("")(0).getElementsByTagName("Span")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
    End If
```

Question) What is the correct class for the href element?

I DO NOT need the code written, I just need to know what the Variation is. I have tried all tags in one order or another, I just can't work out the correct order.

---

HTML image:

[image: image html]

'''#################    Updated Today 17.2.2021 10:30 uk time ################

I am still not able to extract the url, this is the code for now, with QHarr recommendation. Which I am sure was one of the first variations that I used. This looks straight forward, however I can not work it out.

If I leave the code as is then it pulls of nothing
[image: walmart results]

If I remove the (0) from the top row then I get a Error Message, so I have left it in

[image: Error in code]

```
    StartRow = wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    EndRow = wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    varLinks = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(wsSheet.Range("A" & StartRow & ":A" & EndRow))
        
    Counter = 0
    For Each link In varLinks
        Set doc = NewHTMLDocument(CStr(link))
        ''''Get Link 1
        If doc.getElementsByClassName("seller-name")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = "-"
        Else
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("seller-name")(0).href
        End If
```

'########################   Updated 19/2/2020    ########################

This is now working Thanks QHarr. For some reason I had to log off my pc and try it the next day, this is now fixed

Comment: What is Set doc = NewHTMLDocument(CStr(link))?
Is it this function? https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/convert-code-from-ie-to-xmlhttp.1141872/post-5532576

Comment: I have a list of urls in column A of a sheet, the issue I had with the code was that it would not STOP and START at the right url so Dan_w help fix it for me.

Comment: `seller-name` is the class name so `wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("seller-name")(0).href` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks QHarr. I will give it a shot, however I think I have already tried this

Comment: Thanks QHarr, I got this working, for some reason I had to log off my pc and try it the next day, this is now working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now working. Big Thanks QHarr. For some reason I had to log off my pc and try it the next day, this is now fixed

```
    StartRow = wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    EndRow = wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    varLinks = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(wsSheet.Range("A" & StartRow & ":A" & EndRow))
        
    Counter = 0
    For Each link In varLinks
        Set doc = NewHTMLDocument(CStr(link))
        ''''Get Link 1
        If doc.getElementsByClassName("seller-name")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = "-"
        Else
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("seller-name")(0).href
        End If
```